# R for loop through data frame, import and export commands?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm seeking insight as to if it's possible to create a loop to apply to an entire chunk of code (i.e. not just a matrix or dataframe)?  I would like to create one where every instance of 'Jan8' is replaced by 'Jan18' in the following code:

```
Jan8<-read_excel("C:/Users/sbaizer/Desktop/Work/January8.xlsx")
Jan8<-Jan8%>%mutate(NumberTested=Jan8$`Number of Patients Tested (Virus Detection)`)%>%
  mutate(TestedPositive=(Jan8$`Number of Patients Tested Positive (Virus Detection)`))
Jan8<-Jan8%>%select(State, TestedPositive, NumberTested, InitiatedImmunization, CompletedImmunization)

TableauJan8<-aggregate(x=Jan8[c("TestedPositive", "NumberTested")], list(State=Jan8$State), FUN=sum)
write.csv(TableauJan8, "TableauJan8.csv")
```

Comment: Why not just use Find and Replace option available in most editors. If you are using RStudio editor it is very easy to do. You can use `CTRL + F` on windows or `Command + F` on Mac to find a particular word and replace it with something else.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, will just do that!  Sometimes the answer is right in front of you, right?